# Hi im trying to have my if statement equal to more then one number

Tags: java, if-statement

I know this is incorrect and I cant figure it out. Do I just need to change my whole method? This website also said that this have question has been ask, but none of them help me at all.

```
public Date(int cMonth, int cDate, int cYear, int cDayToDate, String cStrMonth, int dayYear){
        if (cMonth = 01 && 12){
            month = cMonth;
            if (cMonth = 01,03,05,07,08,10,12){
            if (cDate <= 31 ){
            date = cDate;
            }// end of if
            }// end of if(cMonth) months with 31 days
        else if(cMonth = 04, 06, 09, 11){
            if (cDate <=30){
                date = cDate;
            }
}// end of cMonth month within 30 days
```

Comment: There is no such shortcut syntax. You could put all the values in a `List` and test if it contains any of them. Also, one `=` is assignment. And no value is both octal 1 and decimal 12.

Comment: Watch your integer literals. `08`, `09` won't compile

Comment: You want a `Set`, not a list to if you only want to check if it contains something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A switch statement is probably best for this.

```
public Date(int cMonth, int cDate, int cYear, int cDayToDate, String cStrMonth, int dayYear) {
    switch (cMonth) {
        case 1:
        case 3:
        case 5:
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 10:
        case 12:
            if (cDate > 31)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            break;

        case 4:
        case 6:
        case 9:
        case 11:
            if (cDate > 30)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            break;
        case 2:
            int days = isLeapYear(cYear) ? 29 : 28;
            if (cDate > days)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    date = cDate;
}
```

Something closer to what you asked for, but something far, far less efficient is

```
public Date(int cMonth, int cDate, int cYear, int cDayToDate, String cStrMonth, int dayYear) {
    if (Arrays.asList(1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12).contains(cMonth)) {
        if (cDate > 31)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    } else if (Arrays.asList(4, 6, 9, 11).contains(cMonth)) {
        if (cDate > 30)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    } else if (cMonth == 2) {
        int days = isLeapYear(cYear) ? 29 : 28;
        if (cDate > days)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    date = cDate;
}
```

btw numbers which start with `0` are in octal so `08` and `09` are not valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `List` to do it

```
List<Integer> monthList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
monthList.add(4);
monthList.add(6);
monthList.add(9);
monthList.add(11);
if(monthList.contains(cMonth)){
   //do your work
}
```

Comment: @ernest_k The OP need to update her code,since she wrote it like `04`

Comment: even if the types matched, cMonth would be `"4"` not `"04"` when converted to a String.

Comment: @lucumt added +1, `Arrays.asList(...)` might be cleaner, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (cMonth = 01 && 12)
```

For this to be true the month must be 1 and 12, I don't think that's possible. I guess you want to check if the month is between 1 and 12, so it should be

```
if (cMonth >= 1 && cMonth <= 12)
```

Also this:

```
if (cMonth = 01,03,05,07,08,10,12){
```

won't work, you should try a switch or simply this (very much typing):

```
if(cMonth == 1 || cMonth == 3 || cMonth == 5 || cMonth == 7 || cMonth == 8 || cMonth == 10 || cMonth == 12)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues:

- Comparison is done with `==`, not `=`. `=` is assignment.
- Numbers with leading `0`s like `01` and `02` and such are octal. You probably wanted `1`, `2`, and such which are decimal.
- You're expecting `&&` to know what you want to compare `12` with, but `&&` doesn't work that way. **Both** operands to `&&` need to specify what you're comparing.
- `&&` means "AND". If you want to follow a branch if `cMonth` is 1 **or** if it's 12, you want `||` ("OR").
- `cMonth = 04, 06, 09, 11` also needs you to be explicit about what you want to do with `06`, `09`, and `11`.

So your outermost `if` needs to be:

```
public Date(int cMonth, int cDate, int cYear, int cDayToDate, String cStrMonth, int dayYear){
    if (cMonth == 1 || cMonth == 12){
        // ...
    }
    else if(cMonth == 4 || cMonth == 6 || cMonth == 9 || cMonth == 11) {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

I'll leave the inside of the branches to you, applying the list of notes above.

Separately: You might look at using a `switch` statement instead of all of those `cMonth ==` comparisons.

```
public Date(int cMonth, int cDate, int cYear, int cDayToDate, String cStrMonth, int dayYear){
    switch (cMonth) {
        case 1:
        case 12:
            // ...
            break;
        case 4:
        case 6:
        case 9:
        case 11:
            // ...
            break;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<Integer>(new Integer[]{1,3,5,7,8,10,12});
    Set<Integer> set2 = new HashSet<Integer>(new Integer[]{4,6,9,11});
    if(cMonth == 1 || cMonth == 12){
        if(set1.contains(cMonth)){
            if (cDate <= 31 ){
                date = cDate;
            }
        }
        else if(set2.contains(cMonth)){
            if (cDate <= 30 ){
                date = cDate;
            }
        }
    }
```